# Why BIT_LENGTH(str) function in MySQL return the size of Chinese characters is 2 bytes?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, character

MySQL version: `Ver 8.0.34 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

> BIT_LENGTH(str): Returns the length of the string str in bits. Returns NULL if str is NULL.

When I type:

```
select BIT_LENGTH('你好')/8;
```

I got:

```
+----------------------+
| BIT_LENGTH('你好')/8 |
+----------------------+
|               4.0000 |
+----------------------+
```

When I create a table and create a column called 'Hello', and insert '你好':

```
select Hello from chinese_test;
```

```
+-------+
| Hello |
+-------+
| NULL  |
| NULL  |
| NULL  |
| 你好  |
+-------+
```

```
select LENGTH(Hello) from chinese_test;
```

```
select LENGTH(Hello) from chinese_test;
```

```
+---------------+
| LENGTH(Hello) |
+---------------+
|          NULL |
|          NULL |
|          NULL |
|             6 |
+---------------+
```

So, why I got 2 bytes from the BIT_LENGTH funcion. I googled and checked the MySQL Reference Manual (It's thankful that someone will tell me what I missed). There is no related content with the BIT_LENGTH function inside.

I just want to know how the BIT_LENGTH function return 2 bytes of chinese character rather than 3 bytes or 4 bytes.

Comment: Looks like a bug, MariaDB is pretty consistent about asserting the length is 6. Ref [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YjByeBlk). As does [MySQL-8.0.30](https://dbfiddle.uk/T6m_ajal).

Comment: @danblack. Not a bug. See the answer below.

Comment: Suggest using only utf8mb4 (not gb18030).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BIT_LENGTH` result is dependent on your connection character set.

What is the output of:

```
select @@character_set_connection, BIT_LENGTH('你好')/8;
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LKIivOjA).

Comment: Thanks! The encoding world is interesting.

Comment: Stated another way: `HEX(CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY('你好') USING utf8) USING gb18030)) --> 'C4E3BAC3'`